# Why do I get a connection error using qBittorrentAPI?

Tags: python, bittorrent

I'm trying to run some code from [this website](https://pypi.org/project/qbittorrent-api/) but I don't understand why I get this error:
`qbittorrentapi.exceptions.APIConnectionError: Failed to connect to qBittorrent. Connection Error: ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/auth/login (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FA519F5840>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))"))`

The code in question:

```
import qbittorrentapi

# instantiate a Client using the appropriate WebUI configuration
qbt_client = qbittorrentapi.Client(
    host='localhost',
    port=8080,
    username='admin',
    password='adminadmin',
)

# the Client will automatically acquire/maintain a logged-in state
# in line with any request. therefore, this is not strictly necessary;
# however, you may want to test the provided login credentials.
try:
    qbt_client.auth_log_in()
except qbittorrentapi.LoginFailed as e:
    print(e)

# display qBittorrent info
print(f'qBittorrent: {qbt_client.app.version}')
print(f'qBittorrent Web API: {qbt_client.app.web_api_version}')
for k,v in qbt_client.app.build_info.items(): print(f'{k}: {v}')

# retrieve and show all torrents
for torrent in qbt_client.torrents_info():
    print(f'{torrent.hash[-6:]}: {torrent.name} ({torrent.state})')

# pause all torrents
qbt_client.torrents.pause.all()
```

I'd really appreciate some help with this, thanks ahead :)

Comment: Is your qBittorrent Web API enabled on the client and set to those credentials?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. I'm not familiar with this library, but it'd probably help to post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: @Chris um... I don't think I know what you mean. Could you walk me through it or something? I'm sorry it's my first time dealing with something like this.

Comment: @LotemM within the qBittorent app's settings, under "Web UI", make sure it is enabled (first check box) and the username and password is what you want it to be (Under Authentication). Just a side note - this API connects to the qBittorent application and does not act as it's own torrent downloader.

Comment: @Chris that was the problem, I didn't even know there was something I needed to do in the qBittorrent app... didn't find too much info about it on the internet. Thank you so much!